# Availability between two dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, between

I wanted to search the availability between two dates.

Here is my **tbl_booking** table structure

```
slot_id     from_date       to_date       hotel_id
  1         2019-08-02      2019-08-06    2
  2         2019-08-10      2019-08-14    2
  3         2019-08-22      2019-08-24    2
  4         2019-08-28      2019-08-29    2
```

Below are some test cases, this is how the system should work

```
1) I/P Date : 2019-08-08 to 2019-08-09  -> O/P - Available. 
2) I/P Date : 2019-08-16 to 2019-08-18  -> O/P - Available.  
3) I/P Date : 2019-08-11 to 2019-08-15  -> O/P - Not Available. 
4) I/P Date : 2019-08-27 to 2019-08-28  -> O/P - Not Available.
```

Here is the query what i tried

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as available from tbl_booking WHERE 
(from_date BETWEEN '2019-08-08' AND '2019-08-09') AND 
(to_date BETWEEN '2019-08-08' AND '2019-08-09')
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: Note that a test for overlaps is very simple: Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and ends after Event B starts.

Comment: although the test is essentially very simple, apparently almost nobody gets it right on the first attempt.

Comment: For I/P Date '2019-08-08' AND '2019-08-10' It should show available COUNT 1. (Because there is slot(slot_id : 2) between this two dates) but iam getting count 0

Comment: Your TO date of `2019-08-14` in that second slot is not between `2019-08-08` and `2019-08-10`, so the second part of your condition would not be true for these test dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to understand your actual output. From my point of view i think you need this

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) as available from tbl_booking WHERE 
 ('2019-08-08' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date) OR 
 ('2019-08-09' BETWEEN from_date AND to_date)
```